# Is ROLLBACK TRANSACTION required?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
DELETE FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate WHERE JobCandidateID = 10;
DELETE FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate WHERE JobCandidateID = 11;
DELETE FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate WHERE JobCandidateID = 12;
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

What happens if the first delete statement fails? Will the 2nd and 3rd delete statements be executed? The example doesn't have any error handling, will it leave an open transaction in the case of an exception, or will SQL Server rollback the transaction automatically? Open transaction = locked resources, right?

I am deciding whether I must apply TRY...CATCH to stored procedures that use transactions.

I am aware about `set xact_abort on`, but want to know what happens without it.

Here is what I found in docs - Controlling Transactions (Database Engine):

> If an error prevents the successful completion of a transaction, SQL Server automatically rolls back the transaction and frees all resources held by the transaction

However I read in other posts that automatic rollback is not fired.

Comment: [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server: Part One – Jumpstart Error Handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) is an excellent read.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your example, without the use of `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the transaction will continue and commit even if the first statement fails. In the text you quoted, the key words are `if an error **prevents** the successful completion of a transaction`, and a `DELETE` statement failing does not prevent the transaction from completing.

An example of an error that would cause an automatic rollback is if the connection to the database was severed in the middle of a transaction. Further down the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you referenced says:

> If a run-time statement error (such as a constraint violation) occurs
>   in a batch, the default behavior in the Database Engine is to roll
>   back only the statement that generated the error. You can change this
>   behavior using the SET XACT_ABORT statement. After SET XACT_ABORT ON
>   is executed, any run-time statement error causes an automatic rollback
>   of the current transaction. Compile errors, such as syntax errors, are
>   not affected by SET XACT_ABORT.

It's always a good idea to use error handling to catch errors and rollback if needed.

Comment: So it will rollback the failed first delete statement, then start executing the 2nd one, and then in the same way - the 3rd one? And at last will go down to commit statement? That means the error in a single statement will not stop the batch execution, right?

Comment: That's exactly right. Also, I updated my answer to (hopefully) be a little more clear :)

Comment: I read from many sources, such at [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/understanding-transactions-in-sql-server/), that a transaction is **atomic**, in a sense that everything succeeds or fails together. However, in the same link I saw an example that they made which handles errors manually. So am I correct to say that, one should understand transactions as **should** be atomic and not **guaranteed** to be atomic?

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to control the process manually:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

   -- do work

COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR (...)
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: An explanation of this can be found in [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server: Part One – Jumpstart Error Handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html).